# Why does Babel not provide URLSearchParams polyfill for IE11

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs

I'm using Webpack + Typescript + Babel with Babel-Loader. Config useBuiltIns: 'usage'

In my code I have some places where I use URLSearchParams. But it seems that Babel is not polyfilling UrlSearchParmas for IE11. I thought I do not worry about any polyfills with babel. (Other polyfills are working for IE11) 
Is that a normal behaviour or is there something wrong in my code?

I'm not importing anything on my files using URLSearchParams. Maybe babel can not recognize it for this reason?

Comment: Are you using this [polyfill](https://github.com/jerrybendy/url-search-params-polyfill) and including it as per its documentation?

Comment: No because I'm using babel. Maybe I understand something wrong here, but using Babel should make me not worrying on any polyfills.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am having the same problem.

Comment: No, unfortunetaly not. We need a Babel expert here to answer the question =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've asked the question directly on babel github page. 
corejs3 will include a polyfill for url search params. Somebody need to review the PR to update corejs3 in babel.

https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9667

Comment: looks like merged.